# Can the number of items visible in a jQuery Mobile listview be limited?

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile

I would like to have multiple jQuery Mobile listviews on the same page stacked vertically.  Because there may be many items in each list, I want to limit the number of visible items in each list, and allow each list to be scrolled independently.

For example, if I have [three lists with 50 items each](http://bit.ly/Or7JDv), I want a maximum of 10 items to be visible in each list, and be able to scroll through each.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be ideal, given your use case, but you could try using [collapsed listviews](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-collapsible.html).

This way your users can still access all the options, but the display is not as cluttered:

```
​<div data-role="page">
   <div data-role="collapsible">
       <h3>List 1</h3>
       <ul data-role="listview">
           <li>option 1</li>
           <li>option 2</li>
       </ul>
</div>

   <div data-role="collapsible">
       <h3>List 2</h3>
       <ul data-role="listview">
           <li>option 1</li>
           <li>option 2</li>
       </ul>
</div>

   <div data-role="collapsible">
       <h3>List 3</h3>
       <ul data-role="listview">
           <li>option 1</li>
           <li>option 2</li>
       </ul>
</div>


</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```